# Espresso 2.0 - Method annotated with @Test inside class extending junit3 testcase

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-espresso

I got a weird warning `Method annotated with @Test inside class extending junit3 testcase` when using the new `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` class shipped with Espresso 2.0.

My class looks just like the one that Google provided as an example:

```
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MyCoolActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyCoolActivity> {

    private MyCoolActivity mActivity;

    public MyCoolActivityTests() {
        super(MyCoolActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkPreconditions() {
        assertThat(mActivity, notNullValue());
        // Check that Instrumentation was correctly injected in setUp()
        assertThat(getInstrumentation(), notNullValue());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

I've added all necessary things to the build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Is there any way to get this warning away?

Comment: are you using these instructions https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

Comment: So in your build.gradle you also have `// App's dependencies, including test
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
`

Comment: Yup I just forgot to add it to the question since I've stripped the not necessary stuff out of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is a JUnit 3 test case because it extends from `TestCase`.

> @Test annotation is a replacement for the test-prefix naming convention used in JUnit 3. JUnit 4 test classes no longer require to extend TestCase or any of its subclasses. In fact JUnit 4 tests cannot extend TestCase, otherwise AndroidJUnitRunner will treat them as JUnit 3 tests.

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#AndroidJUnitRunner

You could either migrate to [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html) provided by `com.android.support.test:rules:0.4` (or later), or stick with JUnit 3.

<s>Another option is [InstrumentationRegistry](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html), provided by Espresso 2, which has `getInstrumentation()`, `getContext()`, `getTargetContext()` (and more). These methods provide access to the current instrumentation, test context, and target context in a static manner. This makes it possible to write your own static utility methods for use in JUnit 4 test case classes. These utilities would mimic functionality that is currently only available in the base JUnit 3 test case classes.</s> (This is no longer necessary.)

Comment: I got confused... In the AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide they have an example of how to work with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and JUnit4. actually it is the only thing I've found when looking for Junit4 and Android. You say ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is JUnit3, I get it. But the User Guide says it can be used for JUnit4. I actually have an example that is exactly the same as the one in the User Guide and it gives me the warning. Besides, when I try to run it it says "Empty Test Suite"

Comment: Its 2016 android unit testing is still a complete mess